# Как изменить web.config в ходе выполнения?

Tags: c#, sql

У меня выполняется создание базы sql программно динамически. При получении данных выполнения
как записать строку подключения в web.config?

Или, скажем, иметь одну строку подключения с переменным набором параметров?

Answer (score 1):

Хранение таких пользовательских данных в web.config не лучшее решение. Для этого больше подходят пользовательские параметры.

[How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SQLConnectionString = "New Connection String";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```